# NodeJS - How to create fs.ReadStream object manually instead of fs.createReadStream?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, stream, fs

My app receiving a stream via socket.io-stream and I want to use it as a "fs.createReadStream" object (which returns a fs.ReadStream object as per NODE doc).

I want to upload files to box.com (obviously with the incoming stream content) using "box-node-sdk" which requires a "stream" object and works with only "fs.createReadStream". So I cannot directly pipe the incoming stream and rather I have to convert it into a "fs.createReadStream" object in order to make use with the box api.

For eg:
Instead of fs.createReadStream('path/to/file'); //returns ReadStream object

How to create?
myReadStream(stream);

Or how to create?
fs.createReadStream(stream);

Could you please help me?

```js
ss(socket).on('file', (stream, data) => {
        

        var streamFileName = './uploads/'+data.originalName;
  var streamDataSize = data.size;       


  //Method 1 - Using incoming stream directly:
  //Cannot use the stream directly. Not working. No error shown given by box sdk.
  client.files.uploadFile('36155801746', data.originalName, stream, (err) => {

    if (err) {
   //done(err);
    } else {
   //done(null, {message: 'Uploading finished'});
   console.log('Upload to box finished');
    }

  });
  
 
  //Alternative Method 2 - Save the incoming stream into a file and again read that file. This doesn't work either. Fails for larger file size over 10 mb. setTimeout is for 3 seconds and the "boxStream" is produced with the data for 3 seconds of incoming stream.
  
  stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(streamFileName);
  
  //read the file again after few seconds because data is being written by the incoming steram
  setTimeout(() => {
  
          var boxStream = fs.createReadStream(streamFileName);
          client.files.uploadFile('36155801746', data.originalName, boxStream, (err) => {

              if (err) {
                //done(err);
              } else {
                //done(null, {message: 'Uploading finished'});
                console.log('Upload to box finished');
              }

            });
        }, 3000);
  



    
});
```

Comment: You can either just use the stream you already have or you can make a new stream on the same file.  A stream is a stream so unless the stream you have isn't an actual node.js stream (some other incompatible type of stream), you should be able to just use the stream you already have.  Why don't you show the actual code you're trying to use so folks can see more specifically what your problem is.

Comment: I'm new to node so may be wrong, but I don't think this statement is correct -

"You can either just use the stream you already have or you can make a new stream on the same file."

The stream coming from the socket is pure data with chunks whereas fs.createReadStream returns a "ReadStream" object which has the data with chunks plus some additional info like path, filename etc.

Comment: I've added the code that I have. Could you please look into it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Streams are streams; there's nothing special about the type returned by `fs.createReadStream`, and `box-node-sdk` works with any type of stream.

This should work:

```
socketstream(socket).on('my-file', function (stream, data) {
  boxclient.files.uploadFile(parentFolderId, data.name, stream, doneCallback);
})
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but using the stream directly doesn't work. I have posted the code that I have. Box SDK requires a fs.createReadStream.